# How to refer pat token present under setting.xml in pom file

Tags: java, maven, azure-pipelines

I have below scm tag in pom.xml file. I am currently passing pat token in connection so that it can autrozie azure pipeline to comit the next version number in pom file after release.

How can I remove the pat-token from this connecton and refer it from setting.xml file or how to use it a variable so that its not visible to everyone

scm
connection
scm:git:https://pat-token@dev.azure.com/microservice-git-code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could try to install the [Replace Token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension first.Then you could use the #{PAT}# in your pom.xml file.

```
scm connection scm:git:https://#{PAT}#@dev.azure.com/microservice-git-code
```

And create the PAT variable as secret in you pipeline and set the target file as **/pom.xml.

[image: PAT]
[image: settings]

Comment: Does it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that by using the `project.scm.id` tag in the properties file of `pom.xml`